# Touch Event not triggering on UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So, I have 3 different UITableViews in my main UIViewController and I control de content with a SWITCH evaluating which tableview it is in 'cellForRowAt' but just 2 out of the 3 tables trigger the 'didSelectRowAt indexPath' event.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch tableView {
    case checkoutTable:
        //THIS RIGHT HERE IS NEVER EXECUTED
        if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 0 {
            if self.calculateTotalsInCart() > 0 {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "sgAddDescount", sender: self)
            }else{

                let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Descuento Inaplicable", message: "No puedes aplicar descuento a una cuenta en ceros", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                let okButton:UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(okButton)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        break
    case clientTable:
        if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 0 {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "clientSelection", sender: self)
        }
        break
    default:
        print("None Selected")
        break;
    }
}
```

When I click any other UITableView the method is called, but with this specific table it isn't.

I set the delegate and datasource of the table too

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qMel.jpg

Comment: Firstly did you set correctly the `delegate` of the `checkoutTable`?

Comment: yes, updated the post

Comment: Is userIneractionEnabled set to true both on your table view and it's table view cells?

Comment: yes, checked them and re-checked them

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no issues as far as i know, but there may be something you missed out somewhere which i could not figure it out on reading your texts.here is an alternate approach which is simple and it can help you,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (tableView.tag == 200) {
        //checkoutTable
    }
    if (tableView.tag == 201) {
        //clientTable
    }
    if (tableView.tag == 202) {
        //your third table
    }
}
```

I hope this could help You out.

Comment: Probem is, the Event is never called when clicked on this specific table

Answer (score 0):

Check whether Selection in Attributes inspector is Single Selection and not No Selection. Also just enable Selection of tableview in viewDidLoad

```
tableView.allowsSelection = true
```